# What is "self" and how was the "view" property used?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, self

In this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick: (id)sender {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Fo Sho?"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:@"fo sho"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

A UIButton would be linked to this "buttonClick" IBAction but what is "self"?

Comment: Voting to close as this is a likely duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950155/iphone-obj-c-where-does-this-view-property-come-from

Comment: exact duplicate of the other question

Comment: It's also close to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883973/is-self-a-pointer

Answer (score 1):

`self` is the equivalent to `this` in many other languages such as C++. In other words when you call `[myString length]`, the `self` pointer inside the `length` message is the pointer to your string named `myString`.

```
-(void)logScore
{
    NSLog(@"%@ score is %d", self.name, self.score);
}

[player logScore];
```

In the example, `self` is the `player` object.

Comment: what about in my specific example? Would it be UIButton or UIView or UIViewController?

Comment: if buttonClick is method of View controller, then it will be view controller.
if buttonClick is method of View then it will be view.

Comment: It would be an instance of the class to which the `#buttonClick:`-Method, you are showing to us, belongs to. Most probably an `UIViewController` but since you are not showing us any more code this is just a guess